# VT-X on windows 7 cannot be recognized by Guest OS(Ubuntu 12.04) with virtualbox

Tags: linux, windows, ubuntu, virtualbox, kvm

I have met with the following problem.
Hardware: DELL Laptop E6430(CPU: I7 3520M)
Host OS : Windows7 professional(64 bit)
Guest OS: Ubuntu 12.04(32 bit)
VMM:      virtualbox 4.2.16

I need to do some development on KVM with a windows 7 environment. Things can be made sure are that VT-X are opened in BIOS and can be recognized by windows 7.(Passed securable test.)

I can't post screenshot for my low reputation, sorry for that :-(

VT-x| AMD-V option in virtualbox is also opened.

But when I typed cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep vmx, I found no related output.
I tried to close VT-D in BIOS and then reopened it as google told me, but in vain.

Note that after I closed VT-D in BIOS, virtualbox just told me that vt-x | AMD-V was not available anymore, which I suppose means virtualbox knows the existence of that CPU feature.

So I thought KVM can not be used by windows 7, am I right? If not, I hope that somebody can tell me why there is no VMX in my guest OS. Thanks in advance!

Comment: It came to me that my issue is about full virtualization which virtualbox doesn't support, so I need to use some other VMMs instead of it, any recommendations?

Comment: Install a real Linux distribution on your real laptop (using separate disk partitions). Don't use VMs.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for answering, I finally installed Ubuntu 12.04 with windows7 on the same hard disk. As for my issue, virtualbox don't support full virtuallization, so I could not see any VMX feature in my Guest OS, but vmware do, which suits me well.

Comment: Please add Comments to the Commentsectrion or update your question. :)